# Can you find a minimal polynomial of $A^n$ if you know the minimal polynomial of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Can you find a minimal polynomial of $A^n$ if you know the minimal polynomial of $A$?

- I'm talking about minimal polynomials of matrices.
- I'm asking in the general sort of way, I know that in some cases you can use algebraic tricks
  or some other cleverness.
- $n$ is just some integer, it's not connected to the matrix in any way.

Comment: What is $n$? Is it the size of the matrix, or just some integer?

Comment: If $f(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $A$, then the subring of the matrix ring generated by $A$ is isomorphic to $K[\alpha]/f(\alpha)$.  Your question is then the same as asking for the minimal polynomial of $\alpha^n$ over $K$. In particular the answer should depend only on $n$ and on the minimal polynomial of $A$.  On the other hand, we should be able use Jordan canonical form to reduce to the case where the minimal polynomial has the form $(x-\lambda)^m$.

Comment: There are plenty of question related to this on the site. Do a search first.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat $n$ is just some integer, I edited my question to make it clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be answered in general by examining the Jordan structure of $A$. Recall that the eigenvalues of $A^n$ are precisely $\lambda^n$ for each eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$. Multiplicity is preserved.

If the minimal polynomial contains a factor of the form $x^k$ then this is transformed to $x^{\left\lceil\frac{k}{n}\right\rceil}$.

Factors of the form $(x-\lambda)^k$ are preserved as $(x-\lambda^n)^k$. If it happens that we have $\lambda_1^n = \lambda_2^n$ for distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$, then we take on the factor with the largest exponent.